# I am trying to consume a SOAP service with an HTTPS url in Mule with AnypointStudio

Tags: java, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHLv2.png)[I am trying to consume a SOAP service with an HTTPS url in Mule with AnypointStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnDE3.png), but it sends me an error

> "un.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target "

how can I solve that?
*emphasized text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would assume that the web-service you are trying to consume required a SSL certificate.
so when you are configuring your web service consumer component you need to specify/configure the TLS context. click the security Tab and select WS-Security Signature. Click om the green plus sign to open the TLS context dialog
[image]

and in the TLS options panel specify the TrustStore and Keystore path

[image]

so when a request goes to the web-service consumer mule with send along the certificate specified here which tells the web-service host that the request is coming from a valid source and its all OK to send a reply back

Comment: can you help me to configure "Use trust store" and "Use key store" plz ?

Comment: sure i can help. have you been provided with the keystore and truststore. actually in most cases same certificate goes as truststore and keystore. you will also need to password for the certificate to open. you can use any tool such as keyexplorer to look into the certificate to ensure it is the right certificate.

Comment: Thank you, I found this page to create "TrustStore and Keystore".
I believe them but it didn't work out.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html

Comment: in the above link item number 4 says the following command : 
keytool -import -keystore clientkeystore -file client.cer -alias client
so have you verified that the client certificate you are trying to import into keystore is a valid certificate ?

Comment: if it's a valid certificate the one I'm using, but it doesn't work

Comment: what error are you getting. what is the format of your keystore and truststore. are they JKS ?

Comment: if they are JKS.
there I have a question, do I have to use my Certificate or the Certificate of service that I want to consume?
This is the service I want to consume.
https://presiatservicios.impuestos.gob.bo:39118/FacturacionSincronizacion?wsdl